# How to replace objects with "curdoc().clear()" using templates? Is it still possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, bokeh

I am trying to replace some root objects. The method with insert replace works fine.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets.buttons import Button
from bokeh.models import Plot, Column
from bokeh.plotting.figure import Figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
import numpy as np

N = 2
x = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
y = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
p = figure(name='fig', width=300, height=200)
p.scatter(x, y, size=10, fill_color='red',)

def overrides_plot():
    print('Overriding with new plot')
    N = 2
    x = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
    y = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
    p2 = figure(name='fig2', width=300, height=200)
    p2.scatter(x, y, size=10, fill_color='blue',)

    curdoc().clear()
    col = column(children=[p2, ov, ov2], name='main_column')
    curdoc().add_root(col)      # this adds the objects at the bottom, instead of the template place

ov = Button(
    name='override',
    label='Override',
    button_type='success',
    width=50
)
ov.on_click(overrides_plot)

def overrides_plot2():
    print('Overriding with new plot with remove/insert')
    N = 2
    x = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
    y = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
    p3 = figure(name='fig3', width=300, height=200)
    p3.scatter(x, y, size=10, fill_color='black',)

    p = curdoc().select_one(selector=dict(type=Figure))
    c = curdoc().select_one(selector=dict(type=Column))
    c.children.remove(p)
    c.children.insert(0, p3)

ov2 = Button(
    name='override',
    label='Overrides with remove/insert',
    button_type='success',
    width=50
)
ov2.on_click(overrides_plot2)
c = column(children=[p, ov, ov2], name='main_column')
curdoc().add_root(c)
```

With the method `overrides_plot` the objects are added to the bottom instead of the template location:

[image]

Template:

```
{% extends base %}

{% block contents %}

    <div class="container body">
        <div class="main_container">
            <div>
                {{ embed(roots.main_column) }}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

So are this methods still useful?

```
curdoc().clear()
curdoc().remove_root()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are and what you are seeing here, is a perfectly valid behavior. The problem is that the newly created root models have different ids from what bokeh knows from the initial embedding. To workaround this, you can create new roots with the same ids as the original models (so `col = column(id=c._id, ...)`). This way bokeh will embed the new roots in the original slots in the template. However, modifying roots should be the last approach to use. It's much more preferable to modify existing models or layouts (as you do in `overrides_plot2`).